# Unknown SQL error

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I'm creating a table and its producing an SQL error and I can't see why.

```
    statement.executeUpdate("drop table if exists group");
    String group = "CREATE TABLE group" +
         "(groupId INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, " + 
         "groupLeader INT NOT NULL, " + 
         "groupMembers INT NOT NULL, " + 
         "goals INT NOT NULL)";
    statement.executeUpdate(group);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GROUP` is  reserved word. Try with:

```
statement.executeUpdate("drop table if exists `group`");
    String group = "CREATE TABLE `group`" +
         "(groupId INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, " + 
         "groupLeader INT NOT NULL, " + 
         "groupMembers INT NOT NULL, " + 
         "goals INT NOT NULL)";
    statement.executeUpdate(group);
```